# Asp.net get rid of session on server on logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, session, session-cookies

I am having trouble with a security issue of asp.net. On log out I want to make sure the session is destroyed so that someone can't take the same sessionid and auth cookies and edit there cookies and the server still responses to the session.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
Session.RemoveAll();
Session.Clear();
```

I have tried using the following in different orders and still no dice. I can am still logged in if I use the original sessionid and Auth cookies. I want the server to totally forget about that sessionid when I logout. Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using FormAuthentication then you can use

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
```

You can also expire the cookies as follows

```
// clear authentication cookie
HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
```

Comment: Yes sorry I am doing FormsAuthentication.Signout() as well and didn;t mention it

Comment: Ok I did more testing and this does clear the cookies out of the browser but not from the server any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using forms authentication, you are probably not calling FormsAuth.SignOut();